# Can this be a strategy to defend csrf? (double submit cookie)

Tags: javascript, security, vue.js, csrf, nuxt.js

used framework: nuxt.js + spring boot(api)

1. Invoke once api to generate random values and set httpOnly cookie(e.g. key=csrfToken) when the page is first accessed.
2. The api response is also stored in vuex.
   (the response also has token body. with Set-Cookie header.)
3. When request using axios, If there is the "csrfToken" cookie, add custom header(e.g. key=CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER) to the request.
4. In the server, if csrfToken cookies are delivered, look up the custom header values to compare them to see if they are the same.

I know that $store is not secure in itself. However, I think CSRF is defensible because $store is not accessible from outside sites.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with me.

Comment: Why send the CSRF token as a cookie at all? Why not just send it in the api response body only?

Comment: @Bergi — Because you'd have nothing do compare it to if you did that.

Comment: @Quentin Usually CSRF tokens are stored on the server to be compared against, or they are encrypted and signed to assert their integrity.

Comment: @Bergi — If it was stored on the server then you'd need a session token in the cookie instead. Still needs a cookie.

Comment: @Quentin I was assuming that the session cookie (given the session is what the attacker is targeting through CSRF) would be sent along anyway.

Comment: You seem to be describing the [double submit cookie technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF#Double_Submit_Cookie)

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Talk:Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Is_this_statement_really_correct.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When request using axios, If there is the "csrfToken" cookie, add custom header(e.g. key=CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER) to the request.

Since the cookie is httpOnly, you wouldn't be able to tell if there was or not.

---

A CSRF attack works by tricking the user into making a request that they didn't intend to make.

The traditional way to do this is to have a form on an attacking website which has the `action` sent to the website being attacked. When that form is submitted, the request comes from the user's browser and has all the user's cookies for the target website included.

The defence against this is to require that the request includes information that the attacking site cannot know. The CSRF token.

Since the attacking site can't read that token from the user's cookies or the site's session store (depending on where it was stored) or from anywhere else, they can't include it in the form data.

---

But you aren't using a regular form submission. You are using JavaScript to make the request.

This comes with a built-in defence: [The Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and [Preflight Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

All you need do is force the request to be preflighted (e.g. by setting the `Content-Type` request header to `application/json` and including a JSON payload in the body).

This will force a request from the attacking site to make a preflight request. Your server won't have the attacker whitelisted. The browser will therefore never make the attacking request.

If the attacker tries to make a non-preflighted request, it won't have the JSON payload, so your server can reject it as malformed.

Comment: That the OP uses JS to make his legit request does not imply a defence against CSRF - the cross-site requests might be done using any technology. I think you mean "*By using JS to make your request, you are able to use techniques that the allow the server to take precautions against CSRF*".

Comment: @Bergi – If they don't use JS, then they are either using something built into HTML (so also won't have the JSON formatted body) or aren't using the user's browser (so won't be making a CSRF attack at all).

Comment: @Quentin When get the random value, the response has 'Set-Cookie' and also body content 'accessToken: xxx'. And when receive the response, the token is stored in the vuex as well as cookie. So when request using axios, I think javascript can check whether the token exists.